# How to prevent CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fail with duplicate_table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 14.7 database with multiple clients that automatically create and delete partitions for a table. One of the clients failed to create a table partition, it got a 42P07 `duplicate_table` error:

> relation "prc_739214" already exists

Even though the query it executed was like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prc_739214 PARTITION OF prc FOR VALUES FROM ... TO ...;`. I was expecting `IF NOT EXISTS` to prevent `duplicate_table` errors, but apparently they may still happen.

Is there any way to harden this query to avoid `duplicate_table` errors?

For reference, the clients received the below error from `epgsql` (the Erlang PG client library):

```
{error,
 error,
 <<"42P07">>,
 duplicate_table,
 <<"relation \"prc_739214\" already exists">>,
 [{file,<<"heap.c">>},
  {line,<<"1200">>},
  {routine,<<"heap_create_with_catalog">>},
  {severity,<<"ERROR">>}
 ]}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is an error? Not a notice?
Here is what I found in the Postgres Doc: "Do not throw an error if a relation with the same name already exists. A notice is issued in this case. Note that there is no guarantee that the existing relation is anything like the one that would have been created."

Could you edit your question with the entire error/notice?

Comment: @KarineBauch yes, it's an error. I've added the exact error message above, it comes from this point in the PG source code: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_14_7/src/backend/catalog/heap.c#L1200

Comment: The CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS query in PostgreSQL is supposed to prevent the duplicate_table error by not executing the CREATE TABLE command if a table with the same name already exists, right?

Comment: You don't get an error, that's what NOT EXISTS does: `relation "prc_739214" already exists, skipping`. See `skipping`

Comment: By the way, the code can be found here: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_14_STABLE/src/backend/commands/createas.c#L423C49-L423C49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IF NOT EXISTS is meant to deal idempotency, not concurrency. If two sessions tries to create the same table at the same time, one of them will still get an error.

I wouldn't have expected it to be **this** error, but with a simple test I see that in the case where the tables are partitions, indeed this is the way the error presents.

So to prevent it, you would need to take some kind of lock to prevent multiple sessions from trying to create the same table at the same time.  The best way to do this would depend on things we don't know about the inner workings of your programs.  Maybe an advisory lock on a hash of the incipient table name, maybe some self-exclusive lock on the parent table of the partitioning tree.

Comment: Thanks, I think the easiest solution for my case would be to simply accept `duplicate_table` results too.